# EKS Cluster in a private subnet - unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create a EKS cluster in a private subnet. I'm having issues getting it working. I get the error `unhealthy nodes in the kubernetes cluster`. Wonder if its due to security group or some other issues like VPC endpoints?

When I use NAT gateway setup then it works fine. But I don't want to use nat gateway anymore.

One think I'm not sure is should the EKS cluster subnet_ids be only private subnets?

In the below config I'm using both public and private subnets.

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "main" {
  name      = var.eks_cluster_name
  role_arn  = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = concat(var.public_subnet_ids, var.private_subnet_ids)
    security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.eks_cluster.id, aws_security_group.eks_nodes.id, aws_security_group.external_access.id]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access  = false
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Cluster handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EKS managed EC2 infrastructure such as Security Groups.

  depends_on = [
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_eks_cluster_policy",
    "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_eks_service_policy"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any NAT gateway to provide internet access for nodes in private subnets?

Comment: No nat gateway. I don't want to use Nat gateway since its price is higher. I had a different setup which had nat gateway and that worked fine. But I want to implement without a nat gateway and use vpc endpoints.

Comment: What should be the method for using VPC endpoints instead of nat gateway?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out without a NAT gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have NAT gateway/instance, your nodes **can't connect to the internet** and fail as they can't "communicate with the control plane and other AWS services"  (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html#vpc-cidr)).

Thus, you can use **VPC endpoints** to enable communication with the plain and the services. To view the properly setup VPC with **private subnets** for EKS, you can check [AWS provided VPC template for EKS](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/cloudformation/2020-10-29/amazon-eks-fully-private-vpc.yaml) (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html)).

From the template, the **VPC endpoints** in `us-east-1`:

- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ec2
- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.api
- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3
- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.logs
- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.dkr
- com.amazonaws.us-east-1.sts

Please note that all these endpoints, escept S3, are **not free**. So you have to consider if running cheap NAT instances or gateway would be cheaper or more expensive then maintaining these endpoints.